# Consider annotating `ItemChange` with `#[derive(Hash)]` but it doesn't work

Tags: rust, hashmap

I am trying to create a struct that has a hashmap of changed values.

Example:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Eq, PartialEq)]
struct ItemChange {
    time: i64,
    metadata: HashMap<String, String>,
    changed_metadata: HashMap<String, String>,
    user_defined_description: String,
    description: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct ProductItem {
    id: String,
    /// Ordered change_history by date
    change_history: HashMap<ItemChange, i64>,
}

impl ProductItem {
    pub fn add_change(&self, change: ItemChange, date: i64) {
        self.change_history.insert(); // <-- change_history doesn't have insert :( 
    }
}
```

The code doesn't compile with an error saying

```
58 | struct ItemChange {
   | ----------------- doesn't satisfy `ItemChange: Hash`
...
97 |         self.change_history.insert();
   |                             ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `ItemChange: Hash`
help: consider annotating `ItemChange` with `#[derive(Hash)]`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try what it suggests? i.e. adding `Hash` to the derivations for `ItemChange`? The key type has to implement `Hash`. You also need to pass arguments to `insert`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried but it didn't change. insert has no params in my example but in real one it does :) sorry for confusion

Comment: please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clearly states your issue

Comment: Probably doesn't work because `HashMap` doesn't implement `Hash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a type to be used as a key for a `HashMap`, it must implement `Hash`. The easiest way to do this for your own `struct` is to derive the trait, however in this case you run into other issues.

As kmdreko mentioned in their comment, the problem is that `HashMap` doesn't implement the `Hash` trait, which means it cannot be used as a key. Therefore, you can't derive `Hash` on a struct that has a `HashMap` field because `#[derive(Hash)]` [requires every field to be implement `Hash`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html#implementing-hash).

A minimal example like this shows a more useful compiler error:

```rs
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Hash)]
struct TestStruct {
    hashmap: HashMap<u32, i32>,
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `HashMap<u32, i32>: Hash` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:5:5
  |
3 | #[derive(Hash)]
  |          ---- in this derive macro expansion
4 | struct TestStruct {
5 |     hashmap: HashMap<u32, i32>,
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Hash` is not implemented for `HashMap<u32, i32>`
  |
  = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Hash` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

I don't see an easy way around this without changing your struct. One way would be to replace the `HashMap`s with another data structure which represents the same data but also implements `Hash`, such as `Vec<(String, String)>`. This will likely have worse performance depending on how you use the hashmaps, and it will need changes to all the code which interacts with them.

Edit: If you decide to use `Vec<(String, String)>`, you will also need to ensure that the vec is sorted so that two vecs containing the same key-value pairs have the same hash, which is not the case if the elements are not ordered the same.